# error: call to undeclared function 'mysql_ssl_set'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations

Tags: mysql, ruby, bundler

I'm trying to `gem install mysql2`

```
~/s/r/railties> gem install mysql2
Fetching mysql2-0.5.6.gem
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.6/ext/mysql2
/Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_absint_size()... yes
checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... yes
checking for rb_gc_mark_movable()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enc_interned_str() in ruby.h... yes
-----
Using --with-openssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3
-----
-----
Using mysql_config at /opt/homebrew/bin/mysql_config
-----
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_DISABLED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_PREFERRED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_REQUIRED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_VERIFY_CA in mysql.h... yes
checking for SSL_MODE_VERIFY_IDENTITY in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL.net.vio in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL.net.pvio in mysql.h... no
checking for MYSQL_DEFAULT_AUTH in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN in mysql.h... yes
checking for SERVER_QUERY_NO_GOOD_INDEX_USED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SERVER_QUERY_NO_INDEX_USED in mysql.h... yes
checking for SERVER_QUERY_WAS_SLOW in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_ON in mysql.h... yes
checking for MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_OFF in mysql.h... yes
checking for my_bool in mysql.h... no
checking for mysql_ssl_set() in mysql.h... no
-----
Don't know how to set rpath on your system, if MySQL libraries are not in path mysql2 may not load
-----
-----
Setting libpath to /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.3.0/lib
-----
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.6/ext/mysql2
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20240216-22567-u1f6tb sitelibdir\=./.gem.20240216-22567-u1f6tb clean

current directory: /Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.6/ext/mysql2
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20240216-22567-u1f6tb sitelibdir\=./.gem.20240216-22567-u1f6tb
compiling client.c
In file included from client.c:15:
./mysql_enc_name_to_ruby.h:43:1: warning: a function definition without a prototype is deprecated in all versions of C and is not supported in C2x [-Wdeprecated-non-prototype]
mysql2_mysql_enc_name_to_rb_hash (str, len)
^
./mysql_enc_name_to_ruby.h:86:1: warning: a function definition without a prototype is deprecated in all versions of C and is not supported in C2x [-Wdeprecated-non-prototype]
mysql2_mysql_enc_name_to_rb (str, len)
^
2 warnings generated.
compiling infile.c
compiling mysql2_ext.c
compiling result.c
result.c:304:35: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
        precision = field->length - (field->decimals > 0 ? 2 : 1);
                  ~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
compiling statement.c
linking shared-object mysql2/mysql2.bundle
ld: library 'zstd' not found
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mysql2.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/dorianmariefr/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/extensions/arm64-darwin-23/3.3.0/mysql2-0.5.6/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 3):

I installed mysql2 with the warning disabled:

```
gem install mysql2 -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
```

Then I got a library not found error.

```
ld: library 'zstd' not found
```

So I linked the library and the disabled the warning when installing mysql2:

```
gem install mysql2 -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" --with-ldflags=-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zstd/lib
```

(macOS Sonoma)

And if you want to configure it globally:

```
bundle config build.mysql2 '-- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" --with-ldflags=-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zstd/lib'
```

And in your `~/.bundle/config` you should have something like:

```
---
BUNDLE_BUILD__MYSQL2: "-- --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

Comment: Maybe explain the actual error and why these solutions helped. Right now all you have provided is a potential for blind copy/paste, brute force type solution that may or may not work for everyone. I notice you use SO as sort of a repository for your own issues/solutions but please remember this is a community for everyone and your questions and answers should both be targeted as though they are legitimately asked and answered under the guidelines of the community.

Comment: @engineersmnky I've added explanations